# Using 3D Vision on LG passive 3D screen from laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, tv, 3d-vision

I own an LG TV with passive 3D technology and an ASUS N76VZ laptop (GT650M card by nVidia).

I would like to play 3D games, according to the appropriate resolution/detail level that the card can handle, using my TV as 3D screen.

I see no 3D Vision menu in my nVidia Control Panel. I thought the card doesn't support 3D Vision but [this page](http://3dvision-blog.com/tag/geforce-gt-650m/) says the contrary.

### Questions:

1. Can GT650M play 3D games using 3D Vision technology?
2. Can a passive TV (so not one using 120hz and shutter glasses) be used as 3D screen with nVidia 3D Vision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2: YES

The 3D Vision settings menu is available only when 3DTV is connected via HDMI and selected as only screen (use <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)